# Why can't my regular expression find the result?

Tags: python, regex

The data is like this:

```
post date='2008-7' postCount='8' viewCount='24308' questionCount='5' answerCount='76' answeredQuestion='5'
```

and here is my code for the task:

```
p1 = re.compile(r"post date")
m1 = p1.search(postline) 
if m1:
    month = re.search(r'post date="([\d\W]+)"', postline).group(1)
```

Answer (score 4):

You're searching for double qoutes `"` whereas your example is with single qoutes `'`.

```
re.search(r'post date="([\d\W]+)"'
                      ^         ^
```

.

```
post date='2008-7' postCount='8' viewCount='24308' questionCount='5' answerCount='76' answeredQuestion='5'
          ^      ^
```

**Edit:** The problem is no longer within the regex but your python. Here's an example:

```
import re
postline = "post date='2008-7' postCount='8' viewCount='24308' questionCount='5' answerCount='76' answeredQuestion='5'"
pattern = "post date='([\d\W]+)'"

p1 = re.compile(pattern)
date = p1.search(postline).group(1) 
print date
```

Outputs:

```
2008-7
```

Comment: I have changed the code like this: month = re.search(r"post date='([\d\W]+)'", postline).group(1), but it is still not working:(

Answer (score 0):

Will your date always be in the format `YYYY-M`? If so, construct your pattern accordingly? This pattern allows for `YYYY-M` or `YYYY-MM`:

```
>>> import re
>>> postline = "post date='2008-7' postCount='8' viewCount='24308' questionCount='5' answerCount='76' answeredQuestion='5'"
>>> pat = r"post date='(\d{4}-\d{1,2})'"
>>> re.search(pat, postline).group(1)
'2008-7'
```